# Using `polymer serve` with local API server

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html, polymer-cli

I want to use `polymer serve` to serve my LitElement app during development without waiting for `polymer build` to finish after every change. However, the app uses relative URLs for API access, like `GET /api/api_method`, and AFAIK I can't make `polymer serve` and my server work on the same port (e.g. `localhost:8080`).

Currently I run `polymer build` and then run my local Python server, which serves the Polymer files as static.

The ideal scenario would be:

```
$ run_my_server.sh --port=8081
$ polymer serve --api_server="localhost:8081"
```

Then for routes that are found in the polymer build directory they would be served, otherwise the request would be routed to `localhost:8081`.

Are there any other ways to setup the local dev process without rebuilding the whole app after every change?

Comment: Do you necessarily have to call the APIs with relative urls? Can't you use an absolute base url?

Comment: @Umbo That would be error prone - imagine you forget to change it back from `localhost` before deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you would do this with a proxy middleware - however, polymer server does not allow to add your own middleware.

So you have 2 options:

1. basically what you are doing e.g. wrapping polymer serve and forward requests
2. use a different server that supports a proxy middleware

As an example the es-dev-server.

install

```
npm i -D es-dev-server koa-proxies
```

create a `es-dev-server.config.js`

```
const proxy = require('koa-proxies');

module.exports = {
  port: 9000,
  middlewares: [
    proxy('/api', {
      target: 'http://localhost:8081',
    })
  ],
};
```

start with

```
es-dev-server --node-resolve
```

Now if you hit http://localhost:9000 you will be served by the es-dev-server. However, if you hit http://localhost:9000/api then it will actually serve from your api server.

Doing this allows to simply use fetch when requesting from the api as all get served from the same domain + port.

You can find more details for here: https://open-wc.org/developing/es-dev-server.html#custom-middlewares-proxy

PS: I am a co-maintainer

Comment: But that doesn't solve the main issue (hot reload), does it? I'm fine with the `polymer build` workflow, but it takes up to two minutes to see the changes in browser.

Comment: es-dev-server sends individual files as is (only with bare module imports replaced) - combining this with standard browser cache and cache headers allows for fast (automatic) reloads... give it a try and if it's not fast enough let us know with a reproduction so we can take a look :)

Comment: I think es-dev-server is broken; my index.html is not loading properly. No matter which combination I try the polymer app is not loading.

Comment: if you think something is broken it's best to open an issue and explain how to reproduce it